# Firebase Analytics configuration management - Versioning and Deployment

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a Firebase dev environment where I use Firestore Analytics.

I added various custom configurations to Analytics (conversions, funnels, custom parameter reporting, audience, etc...).

2 configuration management questions:

- Are these configurations versioned anywhere?
- How can I deploy these to another project (e.g. prod environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, at least not for developer use.
2. The configurations are all added manually - there is currently no deployment tool for this. Feel free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).